# how can download large files in chunks

Tags: linux, windows-10, internet, internet-connection, download-manager

I'm trying to download a 40GB file and save it directly to my USB Flash Drive because I don't have enough space on my local hard drive for the file.

I am also limited to 10GB download per day on my internet connection, and my USB is formatted FAT32 and so it cannot handle files larger than 4GB.

Is there a way to download a couple 4GB chunks of this file each day and then stitch them together when they're all downloaded?

I am using Windows 10 and also have a Kali Linux live USB key.

Comment: You haven't said which protocol - FTP? HTTP? BitTorrent?  Rsync?  Without that information, it's hard to give a good answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the site where you download from supports resumed downloads, you can use either use `curl` with the `--continue-at` option or `wget` with the `--start-pos` option.

While there is a `--max-filesize` option for `curl`, it just refuses to download the file.

So you can either interrupt the download when the file is large enough, or use an additional program like `pv` (you will probably have to install this package).

Example: Assuming "decimal" GB to be on the safe side, 4 GB = 4000000000, so use e.g.

```
curl --continue-at 8000000000 http://your/file/url | pv -S --size 4000000000 > your-file-name
```

to download the third chunk. (I hope curl handles large numbers correctly, I only checked with small numbers).

Both are standard Linux programs, I don't know if they are available for Windows as well.

Comment: Can you give me an example (curl)
cause i'm new in Linux

Comment: +1 Although "stitch them together when they're all downloaded" part is trivial when you have some Linux experience, I would include a hint for future newbies. The command would be `cat chunk1 chunk2 chunk3 … > /mnt/another-filesystem/file-name`.